# Overriding root log level java.util.logging (logging.properties)

Tags: java

My `logging.propeties` contains:

```
handlers = com.package.my.logging.CustomConsoleHandler
.level = INFO
org.apache.level = WARNING
org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory.level = SEVERE
```

Instead of setting the third-party lib levels to warning, I want to change the root log level (second line above) to `.level = WARNING` and set my package to `com.package.my.level = INFO`. However, when I do that no `INFO` level messages from `com.package.my` is ever written to the log. It seems it is not possible for my package to override the root logger level `WARNING`.

Is that by design? Any workaround, preferably without involving a third-party logging lib?

Comment: have you tried using the Apache's log4j capabilities? It's very convenient than using the built in JDK api's (AND it's free).  Take a look here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/

Comment: Yes, I know about the alternatives (I have previously used Logback with SLF4J which I like), but I prefer to use standard libraries if possible.